# Latex, moving specific parts of texts to column / forcing not to skip to new page

Tags: spacing, formatting

probably a stupid question, but something I haven't really been able to find a solution to. I've been working on a project and I can't seem to be able to get it to display how I want. Is there any way to force it to display how I want it to other than manually removing spaces and hoping for the best?

Here's an image-illustration of how I wish it to display. (The highlighted parts and where I wish them to display).

[image: Picture]

Any suggestions?

Comment: not sure what else you would expect to be able to do other than remove space and/or re-word some text, looking at your image neither of the highlighted texts would fit in the indicated areas.

Comment: ... unless you mean to increase the text block so it uses more of the page, so that page number "1" moves down and leaves room for your text.  (geometry package is probably best way to do that, or simply `\addtolength\texheight{4\baselineskip}` in the preamble